# Create and query Lucene full-text indices which are case-insensitive in neo4j 1.8.x?

Tags: lucene, indexing, neo4j

I need to create and query full text indices which are case insensitive:

I think this is the same use-case described in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/CjGcGulXCcA), but I can't see where/how to specify the options suggested in the answer by Mattias Persson :

> By creating it with this config:

```
{
"analyzer": "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer"
}
```

> I think I'll add so that:

```
{
    "type": "exact",
    "to_lower_case": "true"
}
```

Is this doable via a config file, or (better) via the java API? I can find docs on how to do this [in v2.x](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html), but not for earlier versions (which I'm stuck with, for the moment..)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html for an example how to setup an index for case insensitive.

Be aware that you cannot change the config of an existing index, so the map passed in with "forNodes" must be set upon first access to your index.